# Auto increment id Neo4j to retrieve elements in insert order

Tags: neo4j, cypher, auto-increment

Recently, I am experimenting Neo4j. I like the idea but I am facing a problem that I have never faced with relational databases.
I want to perform these inserts and then return them exactly in the insertion order.
Insert elements:

```
create(p1:Person {name:"Marc"})
create(p2:Person {name:"John"})
create(p3:Person {name:"Paul"})
create(p4:Person {name:"Steve"})
create(p5:Person {name:"Andrew"})
create(p6:Person {name:"Alice"})
create(p7:Person {name:"Bob"})
```

While to return them:

```
match(p:Person) return p order by id(p)
```

I receive the elements in the following order:

```
Paul
Andrew
Marc
John
Steve
Alice
Bob
```

I note that these elements are not returned respecting the query insertion order (through the id function).

In fact the id of my elements are the following:
Marc: 18221
John: 18222
Paul: 18208
Steve: 18223
Andrew: 18209
Alice: 18224
Bob: 18225

How does the Neo4j id function work? I read that it generates an auto incremental id but it seems a little strange his mechanism. How do I return items respecting the query insertion order? I thought about creating a timestamp attribute for each node but I don't think it's the best choice

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to generate sequence numbers in Neo4j then you need to manage this yourself using a strategy that works best in your application.

In ours we maintain sequence numbers in key/value pair nodes where Scope is the application name given to the sequence number range, and Value is the last sequence number used. When we generate a node of a given type, such as Product, then we increment the sequence number and assign it to our new node.

```
MERGE (n:Sequence {Scope: 'Product'})
SET n.Value = COALESCE(n.Value, 0) + 1
WITH n.Value AS seq
CREATE (product:Product)
SET product.UniqueId = seq
```

With this you can create as many sequence numbers you need just by creating sequence nodes with unique scope names.

For more examples and tests see the AutoInc.Neo4j project https://github.com/neildobson-au/AutoInc/blob/master/src/AutoInc.Neo4j/Neo4jUniqueIdGenerator.cs

Answer (score 0):

The id of Neo4j is maintained internally, which your business code should not depend on.
Generally it's auto incrementally, but if there is `delete operation`, you may reuse the deleted id according to the `Reuse Policy` of Neo4j Server.